# How to query from Realm database with distinct results

Tags: swift, realm

How to query from Realm database with distinct results?

e.g. `var schedules = Schedules.objectsWhere("areas.id = '\(idAreas)' distict")` and I need see only unique results.

Answer (score 1):

That's still not supported yet - but definitely will be! You would currently have to iterate schedules manually.

Comment: thx for answer, but what version you are planning to add distinct queries ?

Comment: It hasn't been planned yet. We heavily use user feedback / requests to prioritise the order of feature development. The best is to request new features as Github issues here:[https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues] so that multiple people can indicate the need with +1 comments. I can add it, but its better if you do, so you are notified when it is added.

Answer (score 1):

From the [changelog](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v3.1.2/CHANGELOG.md#310-release-notes-2018-01-16), the v3.1.2 now supports `Results.distinct(by:)` which is awesome.

```
let collection = realm.objects(Schedule.self)
var distinctResults = collection.distinct(by: ["areas.id"])
```